# Which kind of test should I use when dealing with External Endpoints?

Tags: testing, continuous-integration, integration-tests, test-automation

My app has a large dependency on external endpoints. As time passes some of them are changing and evolving. Some of these changes are breaking changes...

So far i have about 10 dependencies for a single project (i have other side-projects too) and keeping it up-to-date is not the easiest task of all...

Integration tests seems too broad and too complex to manage this scenario...

What other kind of tests should i consider for my apps? Is there a way to have theses tests run automatically like once a day also?

Comment: Do you mean run scheduled tests to ensure that the APIs outside of your control still behave the way your code expects? Yes, you can do that. You just need something that can make the appropriate requests and make assertions on the results.

Comment: Perhaps the external endpoints should be managed like public APIs, where these types of breakages are minimized. If you have any say in the matter.

Comment: have you consider using contract testing?

Comment: @Leonardo check out the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@leonardo tks for remminding me about this...
So, after alot of searching and studying I decided to use [contract testing](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/IntegrationContractTest.html) to deal with the ever evolving external dependencies and plain old API tests (automated by [telerik](http://www.telerik.com/teststudio-apis)) to test it’s functionalities…

Comment: This looks like a case of [your answer is in another castle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).

Answer (score 2):

In my company, we have recently implemented the contract testing with a very simple integration of [Postman + Newman + Jenkins](https://solidgeargroup.com/test-automation-api).

We use Postman as IDE for coding the tests and the assertions, [Newman](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman) as Postman command line interpreter and Jenkins as CI system.

I have checked Telerik and looks like it has no free plan. So, I thought that you might be interested also in the "Postman approach".